# "Incompatible Types" error in IDE, but code compiles

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a series of related classes. And there is some inheritance stuff that seems to be throwing off my IDE. However my code compiles just fine.

In my response subclass, I'm trying to restrict the errors field to only contain the error subclass. Ideally, I'd like the public getter to return `List<GWSError>` so that I don't have to keep casting it in other classes that us that method. I've attempted to override the inherited getters and setters to do this, but my IDE keeps giving me an incompatible type error. Both NetBeans and Eclipse give errors on the same methods.

I've included samples of my code below to clarify this. Code not related to this question has been omitted for clarity.

As I mentioned, I don't get any compiler errors when I compile it with Maven directly.

This makes me think there must be a better way to accomplish this. But I don't know what that is.

---

Base Response Class

```
public class WSResponse {

    protected List<WSError> errors;

    public List<WSError> getErrors(){
        if(errors == null){
            setErrors(new ArrayList<WSError>());
        }

        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<WSError> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Response Subclass

```
public class GResponse extends WSResponse{

    @Override //IDE Error: getErrors() in GResponse cannot override getErrors() in WSResponse; return type List<GWSError> is not compatible with List<WSError>
    public List<GWSError> getErrors(){
        if(errors == null){
            errors = new ArrayList<GWSError>();
        }

        return errors;
    }

    @Override  //IDE Error: name clash: setErrors(List<GWSError>) in GtmResponse and setErrors(List<WSError>) in WSResponse have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public void setErrors(List<GWSError> errors){
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public void addError(GWSError error){
        getErrors().add(error);
    }
}
```

Base Error Class

```
public class WSError {

}
```

Error Subclass

```
public class GWSError extends WSError{

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got a fundamental design problem, to be honest - I can't use `GResponse` as any other `WSResponse`. You're narrowing how the subclass is meant to be used, which violates normal inheritance. I'm surprised this works in Maven.

Comment: I can't disagree, but I'm not sure how else to approach this. The GResponse is a special case of WSResponse, so a sub-class seems appropriate. Same thing with the GError. However, the GResponse class is dependent on the extra information in the GError subclass. Is the solution to make GError it's own class? But then it's going to duplicate code from the WSError class. I can accept it's a design issue, but I'm fishing for some feedback on how to address it.

Comment: Your question doesn't actually ask for any feedback on the design - it's just about why it compiles in one place but not in another, which is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that generics are invariant. So, you can't change the return type from `List<WSError>` to `List<GWSError>`.

> I don't get any compiler errors when I compile it with Maven directly.

That surprises me. Your code currently can't compile under any Java compiler level.

I guess you should really make your `WSResponse` class generic. That way you can easily create parallel inheritance hierarchy, as you are trying to do in your case. So, modify your class as:

```
class WSResponse<T extends WSError> {
    protected List<T> errors;

    public List<T> getErrors(){
        if(errors == null){
            setErrors(Collections.<T>emptyList());
        }

        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<T> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

and then extend a concrete parameterized type of this class:

```
class GResponse extends WSResponse<GWSError> {

    @Override
    public List<GWSError> getErrors() {
        return super.getErrors();
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrors(List<GWSError> errors) {
        super.setErrors(errors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of generics and type erasure, the methods are conflicting because they are both fundamentally after compilation just `List`

`List<GWError>` does not inherit from `List<WSError>` this isn't how it works in Java.

This is very well documented here on SO as well on Google in general.

If you just Google the actual error message you will find plenty of well detailed explanations there are two long to go into here.